# Not sure if I am properly writing methods to return true or false

Tags: java, methods, boolean

So for a homework assignment I was tasked with writing code that included 5 static methods. Two of them asked for the following:
"Write a method that takes an integer X as an argument, and returns true if X is even, and false if X is odd."
and
"Write a method that takes a positive integer N as an argument, and returns true if N is prime, and false otherwise. Assume N > 1."
I have written their code

```
public class MethodSignature {

public static boolean evenCheck(int x){
    if(x % 2 == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean primeCheck(int N){
    for(int i=2;i<N;i++){
        if(N % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    int x = 3;
    int N = 5;
    System.out.println(evenCheck(x));
    System.out.println(primeCheck(N));
    }
}
```

It is unclear to me if I am required to have the methods print out true or false. Before I added the println to the method calls they did not print, obviously. So I guess I have two questions: Does a boolean method have to print true/false to return true false? And if I was asked specifically to do that, am I doing it the simplest/most efficient way? Or is there something I am missing?

Thanks a lot you guys.
D

Comment: "Printing" and "returning" are two very, very different things.  Neither one relies on or has anything to do with the other.

Comment: printing is output. returning is sending data back to whatever called the function/method. They're two completely/utterly different things. A "parent" does not magically see anything that a called function outputs.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. You let the `System.out.println()` print out the value you get from the method, which is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Just for optimization: in `primeCheck` you dont have to run all numbers from 2 to `N`. `N/2` is enough as upper limit.

Comment: The evenCheck could be shortened: ``public static boolean isEven(int n) { return (n % 2) == 0; }

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question

> : Does a boolean method have to print true/false to return true false?

No. This is never the case and will not be. But you are right, that a method which declares a return type it has to return the same type in the body.

e.g.

```
public boolean getBooleanValue(); // has to return a boolean   
public void getBooleanValue; // does not return anything, but has a misleading methodname
```

In both methods you can still print out anything. Both have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing to mention here is that **naming** matters. Let me show you what I mean, by quickly re-writting some of your code:

```
public static boolean isEven(int x){
  if(x % 2 == 0){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The point is: that method name already indicates that the method will tell you if the provided argument *is even*.

But coming back to your question: the fact if a method does some kind of *logging* or *tracing* is *orthogonal* to what the method is actually doing. Meaning: the above *isEven* method is there to tell you if a number is even. If **you** think it is helpful that this method also *prints* something / somewhere, then you simply add such code to your method.

In other words: we can't tell you what kind of print statements you would find helpful! Thus - your code, your decision.

When looking at things from a "real world" perspective, then such trace statements can be essential on the one hand; but on the other hand, one would also have a lot of good unit tests around which help to quickly debug problems; thus such trace prints are not a "must have"!

Comment: And I'd probably change the implementation to simply `return x % 2 == 0;`.

Comment: I am not saying that this is the shortest code possible. For a *newbie* my version might be slightly easier to read and *understand* though*.

Answer (score 0):

Printing and returning are two different unrelated things.
Printing is used to notify the user of something;

```
public static boolean evenCheck(int x){
    if(x % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println(x + " is even");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(x + " is odd");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have modified your evenCheck() method to notify the user if the value x is even or odd. The printout is not mandatory and does not affect the code in any way if it is removed, its purely for notification purposes

Because you defined the method with a return type `boolean` - `public static boolean evenCheck(int x)` this requires that you must include a return value of true or false

Answer (score 0):

The assignement specified that the methods retuns a bool, so you do not need to print a value.

You could write you `evenCheck` method in a shorter way:

```
public static boolean evenCheck(int x){
    return (x % 2 == 0);
}
```

The comparison between the result of the operation % and zero is already a bool, there is no need to add an if/else statement.
You are now returning the result of the comparison.

The `primeCheck` method is good but you could add some performance changing the calculation

```
public static boolean primeCheck(int N)
{
    int middle = (int) Math.sqrt(N) + 1;
    for (int i = 3 ; i <= middle ; i=i+2)
    {
        if (N % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

- Number 2 is always prime (ergo always true), you can start the for loop from 3.
- You are checking the prime number against the `half+1` of `N`, there is no need to check all the number after `half+1`.